# Extending functions to querySelector in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to use something like below in vanilla javascript -

```
$("#divA").showTooltip({...});
```

I have figured out that

1. We need to create an alias like below

   `var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);`

and now I can use `$` instead of `document.queryselector` everywhere. But I am limited to use only certain properties.

2. To extend a function showTooltip one possibility is that I need to set a new function on `document.queryselector` aka `$` as below

   `$.prototype.showTooltip((obj) => {.....});`

But here, as $ is not an object so prototype property does not exist and it throws an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'showTooltip' of undefined....
```

I wonder how can we do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The result of `document.querySelectorAll` is not itself.  It's a NodeList or something of that nature.  You're extension of the `showTooltip` would need to be on either the NodeList, or the element type in the list.  Which is n Element or HTMLElement or something of that nature.  You should debug your logic to see these details.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Something like `$('.list-item').showTooltip()` and `showTooltip` will be called for every element in the NodeList?

Comment: Yes. you are right. I want to write a plugin using vanilla JS which shows a tooltip for element(s) which are initialised in this way. Maybe what I am thinking how to do it is not the right way.